# Protege SWRL rule creator says " Unexpected character ''' "; class name has a space in it

Tags: owl, protege, swrl

In the SWRL Tab in Protege I am trying to write a rule, but I can only do so with classes that don't have spaces in them. For example, I have a class called "equipment" in my ontology, so I can do this with no errors:

```
equipment(?x)
```

I also have a class called "machine tool". Because this class a space in its name, it says "Invalid SWRL atom predicate 'machine'" when I do this:

```
machine tool(?x)
```

I tried using an underscore instead of a space but that didn't work. I also tried putting machine tool and quotes as follows but then it says " Unexpected character ''' ":

```
'machine tool'(?x)
```

How do I refer to a class if it the class name has a space in it? Is there some way I can refer to it with the URI instead?

Comment: using the URI instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I figured it out. I had to update the SWRLTab plugin in Protege and then I could refer to the class by its URI as follows:

```
msdl:MSDL_0000070(?x)
```

Comment: Can you add the old version of the plugin, so that future readers know which version of the plugin had this problem?

Comment: @Ignazio I'm not sure how I would figure out what version I was using now that I updated it

Answer (score 2):

`machine tool` is not the name of the class in your ontology, it is the value of an rdfs:label (or rdfs:comment) property attached to the class. The editor is not allowing you to use that (which would be convenient, I guess). A workaround is to find the actual IRI of the class and use that - shortened to its QName if that works.

Comment: The URI for 'machine tool' is http://infoneer.txstate.edu/ontology/MSDL_0000070 .

I tried doing http://infoneer.txstate.edu/ontology/MSDL_0000070(?x), MSDL_0000070(?x), and 0000070(?x), but none of those worked.